# Git is in the PATH, but is not being recognized as a command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, git, environment-variables

I've recently reinstalled Git, and I just can't get it to run off the native Windows command prompt anymore. I'm sure it is in `Path` environment variable, as you can see:

```
C:\Users\Ult>where git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

C:\Users\Ult>git --version
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ult>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe" --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2
```

So far I've tried:

- Close and reopen the command prompt;
- Reinstall Git once again;
- Reboot computer;
- Edit the `Path` environment variable, moving `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` to the beginning of it.

I've already looked around the web and in SU and couldn't find a solution. Please don't close as a dupe of the existing similar questions which are just about not having Git in the `Path` or reopening `cmd.exe`. I've already tried these and they do not solve the issue.

I need to be able to run Git off the native `cmd.exe` in order for some of my IDE/text editors' Git plugins to work properly. That means I can't just use Git Bash (which works fine).

Running on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 6):

Finally found the actual issue: there was a `"` in the `PATH` environment variable.

Everything after `"` was ignored when trying to run executables from `cmd.exe`, although the `where` command could still find them.

Comment: I had a similar problem: I had a space " " just at the end of the PATH variable value due to some wrong script resulting in that situation! `where` was able to ignore this, but not the bash shell itself...

Comment: I had a similar situation as well. On Windows, some of the paths in the PATH variable ended with \ and some didn't. After adding the final \ to all those who did not end with it before - android recognise `git` once again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation
But non of the solutions provided here worked
What worked for me is to leave the \git.exe away and replace it with:

~\git\bin\